# Is it possible to reload iframes in a quick succession?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xss

I'm currently working on a project which includes testing XSS payloads in different browsers. The goal is to find out, if the payloads are still working, or not.
The way I'm approaching this problem is by loading each payload in a seperate, or new, iframe. Since I will be testing a ton of payloads, simply specifying one dedicated iframe per payload doesn't seem feasible. Therefore I need to load the payloads into iframes one after another.

I've tried reloading the iframe by setting the src-Attribute of the iframe like the following:

```js
function testing_iframe2(iframe_id,payload)
{
 //Does work one time, though not consecutively
 document.getElementById(iframe_id).src = "data:text/html," + payload;
}

testing_iframe2("frame1",'<button onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus>');
testing_iframe2("frame1",'<svg/onload="alert(4)">');
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="frame1" class="frames"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, only the second payload is executed.

So here is my question:

**Is it possible to load/reload/create+delete iframes in a quick succession?**(Of course, any other solutions to the problem are gladly appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe1");
var testes = [
 '<svg onload="alert(1);" />',
 '<svg onload="alert(2);" />'
];


iframe.onload = function(){
  if(testes.length > 0){
    iframe.src = "data:text/html," + testes.shift();
  }
}

iframe.onload();
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>
```

Comment: I've played around with your solution, and there seems to be some odd behaviour. I have tried it with the following array of payloads: var testes = [
 '<svg/onload="console.log(1);">',
 '<svg/onload="console.log(2);">',
 '<button onfocus="console.log(3)" autofocus>',
  '<svg/onload="console.log(2);">',
 '<button onfocus="console.log(4)" autofocus id="test">',
  '<svg/onload="console.log(1);">',
 '<svg/onload="console.log(2);">',
  '<button onfocus="console.log(3)" autofocus>',
 '<svg/onload="console.log(2);">'
];
The button XSS-Payload only triggers once.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine in chrome, though in firefox it seems to be buggy. Unfortunatelly I need a more reliable solution.

Comment: @Tastro Mustafa has explained what you need to do, you need to wait for the load event of the iframe before you set `src` yourself, you should play around with that, and potentially creating separate iframes